# Dynamic chart using achartengine

Tags: android, dynamic, charts, achartengine

My app receives data from a device via bluetooth continuously, depending on the data i need to draw the graph.I found achartengine very useful in drawing the chart, now my question is how do i create dynamic graph using achartengine,is it possible?. If not how do i do

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have used the random numbers for the input/data , instead of the actual input from the bluetooth.  complete working project can be found [here](https://www.box.com/s/65d1c23a01430e206342) , thought it might help someone.:)

cheers.

Comment: I was looking for some demo.. just downloaded your file, hope it will help me for dynamic chart. thanks :)

Comment: hey the link is not working can u please share code some where else

Answer (score 2):

So AchartEngine don't manage dynamic or what we call real-time drawing but you can do this by refreshing your graph continuously when you add new data to your Serie like this :

```
private GraphicalView mChartView;// that's your graph view declared before

if (mChartView != null) {

mChartView.repaint();// to refresh the graph 

 }
```

Make the code in your serializing loop or where you need to refresh your graph.

Answer (score 2):

But you have to remove the Previous graph before generating or repaint() so do like this It will definitely help you.

```
private GraphicalView mChartView;// that's your graph view declared before

if (mChartView != null) {
layoutr.removeView(mChartView);

mChartView.repaint();
layout.addView(mChartView);// to refresh the graph 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

one advice if you are testing dynamic graph by in emulator please try to test it in real device because  sometime emulator wont respond properly ,so it will waist lot of valuable time.

```
private GraphicalView mChartView;// that's your graph view declared before

if (mChartView != null) {
layout.removeView(mChartView);//Delete the old graph 

mChartView.repaint();// to refresh the graph 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as current *GraphicalView* is not removed from the layout and re-added again, the graph will not be refreshed. 
Otherwise,  only by touching the layout containing the "GraphicalView" can refresh your graph (via *onTouch* callback).